# Clicking same item closes menu but different item keeps menu open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle, state

I have built a side menu with icons and after clicking each icon a menu slides out with corresponding items on it. By using

```
const handleCloseWhenOpen = menuOpen ? { onClick: this.closeMenu } : null;
```

then putting

```
{...handleCloseWhenOpen}
```

as a prop...this makes it so when I click on icon1 the menu opens and when clicking on icon1 again, the menu closes. If I click on icon1, the menu opens and then click on icon2, instead of just switching menu data, the menu closes and I have to click on icon2 again to get the menu out with the data for icon2. I am only wanting the menu to close when the *same* icon that was clicked to open it, is clicked again.

Any help would be awesome.

```js
export default class SidebarNav extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any,
  };
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      menuOpen: false,
      sideBarItems: new List(),
      isSelected: false,
    };
  }

  openMenu = (value) => {
    let menuData = [];
    switch (value) {
      case 'icon1':
        menuData = Data.icon1Data;
        break;
      case 'icon2':
        menuData = Data.icon2Data;
    }
    this.setState({
      menuOpen: true,
      sideBarItems: menuData,
      selectedIcon: value,
    });
  }

  closeMenu = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      menuOpen: false,
      selectedIcon: value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
            menuOpen,
            sideBarItems,
            selectedIcon,
          } = this.state;
    const { children } = this.props;
    const handleCloseWhenOpen = menuOpen ? { onClick: this.closeMenu } : null;
    return (
    <PageWrapper>
      <SideNav
        onClick={this.openMenu}
        selectedIcon={selectedIcon}
      />
      <PageContentWrapper>
        <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
          <PushMenu
            visible={menuOpen}
            sideBarItems={sideBarItems}
            {...handleCloseWhenOpen}
          />
          <Sidebar.Pusher {...handleCloseWhenOpen}>
            {children}
          </Sidebar.Pusher>
        </Sidebar.Pushable>
      </PageContentWrapper>
    </PageWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
export default class SideNav extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
    selectedIcon: PropTypes.any,
  }
  render() {
    const {
            onClick,
            selectedIcon,
          } = this.props;
    return (
    <SideBarDiv>
        <IconList>
        {
          Data.icon1Data.map((item, itemIndex) => {
            return (
              <IconWrapper
                key={itemIndex}
                className={
                selectedIcon === item.get('value')
                ? 'Icon-pressed-shadow'
                : 'Icon-right-shadow'
                }
                onClick={() => onClick(item.get('value'))}
              >
                  <ListItem>
                    <Icon name={item.get('name')} />
                      </ListItem>
              </IconWrapper>
            );
          })
        }
        {
          Data.icon2Data.map((item, itemIndex) => {
            return (
              <IconWrapper
                key={itemIndex}
                className={
                selectedIcon === item.get('value')
                ? 'Icon-pressed-shadow'
                : 'Icon-right-shadow'
                }
                onClick={() => onClick(item.get('value'))}
              >
                <ListItem>
                  <Icon name={item.get('name')} />
                  <NotificationLabel>3</NotificationLabel>
                </ListItem>
              </IconWrapper>
            );
          })
        }
      </IconList>
    </SideBarDiv>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
export default class PushMenu extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
    };
  }
  static propTypes = {
    visible: PropTypes.bool,
    sideBarItems: PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List),
  }
  render() {
    const {
            sideBarItems,
            visible,
          } = this.props;
    return (
      <Sidebar
        className='Push-menu'
        animation='push'
        width='thin'
        visible={visible}
      >
      <div>
          {
            sideBarItems ? sideBarItems.map((menuTitle, menuTitleIndex) => {
              return (
                <div key={menuTitleIndex}>
                <Header>{menuTitle.get('title')}</Header>
                <Linebreak />
              </div>
              );
            })
            : <Header>Content</Header>
          }
        </div>
        <List>
          {
            sideBarItems ? sideBarItems.map((menuItem, menuItemindex) => {
              return (
                <li key={menuItemindex}>
                    {
                    !!menuItem.get('childItems') &&
                    menuItem.get('childItems').map((childItem) => {
                      return (
                        <div key={childItem.get('name')}>
                          <ListItemHeader>{childItem.get('name')}</ListItemHeader>
                          <List>
                            {
                              childItem.get('nestedItems').map((nestedItem) => {
                                return (
                                  <ListLink key={nestedItem.get('name')}>
                                    <Link
                                      activeStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
                                      to={nestedItem.get('route')}
                                    >
                                      <li>{nestedItem.get('name')}</li>
                                    </Link>
                                </ListLink>
                                  );
                              })
                            }
                          </List>
                        </div>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </li>
              );
            })
            : null
          }
        </List>
          </Sidebar>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The state in `SidebarNav` has a field `menuOpen` which tracks whether *any* menu is open or not. This is what is checked when your run `handleCloseWhenOpen`.
So, when you click Icon1, `menuOpen` is set to true. Next when you click Icon2 `menuOpen` is checked and found to be true and toggled to false. Thus clicking Icon2 closes the menu of Icon1 rather than opening the menu of Icon2.

What you need to do to correct this behavior is to track the state of each icon menus separately. So, if you want to track the state in `SidebarNav`, you can have a field in the state object for each of the icons e.g.

```
this.state={
    .....
    menu1Open:false,
    menu2Open:false,
    .....
}
```

and then check which field you need to toggle, depending on the icon that was clicked; and render the menus accordingly.

If you think this would get complicated, you can let each `SideNav` track its own state, pass the menu data as props to the Icon and let the click action toggle the menu's opening and closing.

Comment: What do you mean by "a field for each of the icons"? Like a prop?

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. This is the answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: If I think it will get messy, which I think it will because there are 12 icons/menu's...The second option is to let SideNav track its own state. So I just do the constructor in the SideNav component correct? I've edited the original post to include the PushMenu component.